# R mapping (ideally TMAP) - draw polygon of area(s) that are not within 500 metres of any data points within dataset

Tags: r

I have a dataset with several hundred geographical points expressed as lat/long values that I plot as dots using tm_dots, on top of some boundaries that I plot using tm_shape (both using tmap).

Does anyone know of a way that I can draw polygons to represent areas within the boundaries of the underlying layer that are not within 500 metres of any of the points plotted? I'd be happy to use other R mapping resources (e.g. ggplot/ggmap) if better for this task.

Current code is:

```
    #Call necessary packages
    library(tidyverse)
    library (readxl)
    library(maptools)
    library(classInt)
    library(RColorBrewer)
    library(sf)
    library(tmap)
    library(scales)
    library(tmaptools)
    library(geodata)

#Read in boundary polygon data
#This shape file is from https://www.data.gov.uk/dataset/2cf1f346-2f74-4c06-bd4b-30d7e4df5ae7/middle-layer-super-output-area-msoa-boundaries
shp_name <- "//ims.gov.uk//homedrive//users//JW2002//My Documents//Data//Demography, Mapping & Lookups//Shape Files//East of England//MSOA//Middle_Layer_Super_Output_Areas_December_2011_Generalised_Clipped_Boundaries_in_England_and_Wales.shp"
    
EofEMSOAs <- st_read(shp_name)%>% 
  st_as_sf()

#Read deprivation data from another source (not specifically relevant to the mapping section of this project but provides list for subsequent subset to East of England MSOAs only)
EofEMSOAsIMD <- read_excel("~/Data/Demography, Mapping & Lookups/IoD/National & EofE IoD 2019/National&IoD 2019 MSOAs.xlsx", 
                           sheet = "East of England MSOAs")

#Subset MSOA list to East of England Only
EofEMSOAsCodeListOnly <- dplyr::pull(EofEMSOAsIMD, "Area Code")
EofEMSOAsCodeListOnly <- paste(EofEMSOAsCodeListOnly, collapse = '|')

EofEMSOAsFinalList <- EofEMSOAs[grep(EofEMSOAsCodeListOnly,  EofEMSOAs$msoa11cd),]
    
#Generate point data
PointData <- read.table(textConnection("ID   Latitude   Longitude
A 52.9742585 0.5526301
B 52.972643 0.8495693
C 52.972643 0.8495693
D 51.46133804 0.36403501"), header=TRUE)
    
#Geocode the point list
PointDataPlotted = st_as_sf(PointData, coords = c('Longitude', 'Latitude'), crs = 4326)

#Remove geometry
PointDataPlotted2 <- PointDataPlotted %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  mutate(buffer = st_buffer(geometry, dist = 5000)) %>% 
  select(-geometry) %>% 
  st_as_sf()

#Create union shape of polygons
union <- st_union(EofEMSOAsFinalList)

# generate bounding box 
mask_union <- union %>% as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(bbox = st_as_sfc(st_bbox(c(xmin = -5.5, xmax = 9, ymax = 51.5, ymin = 42), crs = st_crs(4326)))) %>% 
  st_as_sf() 

# compute difference between bounding box and union polygon to 
# use as mask in the final layer 
diff <- st_difference(mask_union$bbox, mask_union$geometry)

# Build map
OutputMap <- 
  # plot only shapes filled red
  tm_shape(EofEMSOAsFinalList) +
  tm_fill(col = "red") +
  # plot only buffer zones of each point in green
  tm_shape(PointDataPlotted2)+
  tm_fill(col = "forestgreen") + 
  # add mask
  tm_shape(diff) +
  tm_fill(col = "white") +
  # plot borders of shape 
  tm_shape(EofEMSOAsFinalList) +
  tm_borders(col = "white",
             lwd = 1,
             lty = "solid") +
  # add custom legend
  tm_add_legend(type = "symbol",
                labels = c("Restricted", "Public"),
                col = c("red", "forestgreen"),
                title = "Access type",
                size = 1.5,
                shape = 21)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution to find areas within the boundaries of the underlying layer that are within 50 km of any of the points plotted.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(geodata)

# example polygons of France
polygon <- gadm(country = "FRA", level = 1, path = tempdir()) %>% 
  st_as_sf() %>% 
  filter(NAME_1 != "Corse") 

# get 100 sample points within union shape of polygons
set.seed(42)
union <- st_union(polygon)

points <- st_sample(x = union, size = 100, type = "random") %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% # add an id for later joining
  st_as_sf() %>%
  # calculate aound each point a buffer zone of 50km 
  mutate(buffer = st_buffer(geometry, dist = 50000))

# add for each point the polygon (state) in which it is located
points <- st_join(points, polygon, join = st_within) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%  
  dplyr::select(id, NAME_1) %>% 
  left_join(points) %>% 
  filter(NAME_1 != "Corse")

# for each polygon calculate the union shapes of the 
# corresponding buffers zones within
points_buff_union <- points %>% 
  dplyr::select(-geometry) %>% 
  st_as_sf() %>% 
  group_by(NAME_1) %>% 
  summarise() 

# plot content
polygon %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = points_buff_union, aes(geometry = buffer, fill = NAME_1)) +
  geom_sf(fill = NA) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired") +
  geom_sf(data = points, aes(geometry = geometry), color = "black", size = .5)
```

[image]

From this point I guess it's easy to find the areas not within XX meters of any of the points plotted.

If you want to find area across the underlying polygons you can simply use the following (blue areas are within 50 km of any of the points plotted while red areas don't):

```
# calculate union shape for all buffers
points_buff_union <- points %>% 
  filter(NAME_1 != "Corse") %>% 
  dplyr::select(-geometry) %>% 
  st_as_sf() %>% 
  summarise() 

# generate bounding box 
mask_union <- union %>% as_tibble() %>% 
 mutate(bbox = st_as_sfc(st_bbox(c(xmin = -5.5, xmax = 9, ymax = 51.5, ymin = 42), crs = st_crs(4326)))) %>% 
 st_as_sf()

# compute difference between bounding box and union polygon to 
# use as mask in the final layer 
diff <- st_difference(mask_union$bbox, mask_union$geometry)

# plot content
polygon %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(fill = "red3") +
  geom_sf(data = points_buff_union, aes(geometry = buffer), fill = "lightblue") +
  geom_sf(data = points, aes(geometry = geometry), color = "black", size = .5) +
  geom_sf(fill = NA) +
  geom_sf(data = diff, fill = "white")
```

[image]

Of course you can plot the individual layers computed with sf also using tmap:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(geodata)
library(tmap)

# example polygons of France
EofEMSOAs <- gadm(country = "FRA", level = 1, path = tempdir()) %>% 
  st_as_sf() %>% 
  filter(NAME_1 != "Corse") 

# get 100 sample points within union shape of polygons
set.seed(42)
union <- st_union(EofEMSOAs)

PointDataPlot <- st_sample(x = union, size = 100, type = "random") %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  # calculate around each point a buffer zone of 50km 
  mutate(buffer = st_buffer(geometry, dist = 50000)) %>% 
  select(-geometry) %>% 
  st_as_sf()

# generate bounding box 
mask_union <- union %>% as_tibble() %>% 
 mutate(bbox = st_as_sfc(st_bbox(c(xmin = -5.5, xmax = 9, ymax = 51.5, ymin = 42), crs = st_crs(4326)))) %>% 
 st_as_sf() 

# compute difference between bounding box and union polygon to 
# use as mask in the final layer 
diff <- st_difference(mask_union$bbox, mask_union$geometry)

# Build map
OutputMap <- 
  # plot only shapes filled red
  tm_shape(EofEMSOAs) +
    tm_fill(col = "red") +
  # plot only buffer zones of each point in green
  tm_shape(PointDataPlot)+
    tm_fill(col = "forestgreen") + 
  # add mask
  tm_shape(diff) +
    tm_fill(col = "white") +
  # plot borders of shape 
  tm_shape(EofEMSOAs) +
    tm_borders(col = "white",
               lwd = 1,
               lty = "solid") +
  # add custom legend
  tm_add_legend(type = "symbol",
                labels = c("Restricted", "Public"),
                col = c("red", "forestgreen"),
                title = "Access type",
                size = 1.5,
                shape = 21)
```

[image]

**UPDATE using UK data**

```
#Call necessary packages
library(tidyverse)
library (readxl)
library(maptools)
library(classInt)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(sf)
library(tmap)
library(scales)
library(tmaptools)
library(geodata)

# Read in boundary polygon data
EofEMSOAs <- st_read("MSOA_EngWal_Dec_2011_Generalised_ClippedEW_0/Middle_Layer_Super_Output_Areas_December_2011_Generalised_Clipped_Boundaries_in_England_and_Wales.shp")%>%
  st_as_sf(crs = 4326) %>% 
  st_make_valid() %>% 
  # use only a subset of the data
  st_crop(c(xmin = 550000, ymin =320000, xmax = 600000, ymax = 360000)) 

# Generate point data
PointData <- read.table(textConnection("ID   Latitude   Longitude
A 52.9742585 0.5526301
B 52.972643 0.8495693
C 52.972643 0.8495693
D 51.46133804 0.36403501"), header=TRUE)
    
# Geocode the point list
PointDataPlotted = st_as_sf(PointData, coords = c('Longitude','Latitude'), crs = 4326)

# Remove geometry
PointDataPlotted2 <- PointDataPlotted %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  mutate(buffer = st_buffer(geometry, dist = 5000)) %>% 
  select(-geometry) %>% 
  st_as_sf(crs = 4326)

# Create union shape of polygons
union <- st_union(EofEMSOAs)

# generate bounding box 
mask_union <- union %>% as_tibble() %>%
 mutate(bbox = st_as_sfc(st_bbox(geometry), crs = 4326)) %>%
 st_as_sf()

# compute difference between bounding box and union polygon to 
# use as mask in the final layer 
diff <- st_difference(mask_union$bbox, mask_union$geometry)

# Build map
OutputMap <- 
  # plot only shapes filled red
  tm_shape(EofEMSOAs) +
  tm_fill(col = "red") +
  # plot only buffer zones of each point in green
  tm_shape(PointDataPlotted2)+
  tm_fill(col = "forestgreen") + 
  # add mask
  tm_shape(diff) +
  tm_fill(col = "white") +
  #  plot borders of shape 
  tm_shape(EofEMSOAs) +
  tm_borders(col = "white",
            lwd = 1,
            lty = "solid") +
  # add custom legend
  tm_add_legend(type = "symbol",
                labels = c("Restricted", "Public"),
                col = c("red", "forestgreen"),
                title = "Access type",
                size = 1.5,
                shape = 21)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for this wonderful answer. I'm afraid this is a bit beyond my level - I have added the code as I have it at present in to my original post, would you be so kind as to amend that code in order to generate something similar to your second map please? Thank you so much.

Comment: I added a solution using tmap. Since you didn't provide sample data, again I used the data from France. At some points you need to adjust the code for your needs.

Comment: Hi thanks - I'm making progress but the map still isn't looking correct I'm afraid. Would you mind please reviewing my latest alteration to the above code in my original post (including details on where I obtained MSOA polygon data from and a few sample data points now included) and correcting? Thanks so much.

Comment: Using your data, it looks almost the same like for my provided example.